# .htaccess rewrite url with parameters to url with other parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite a URL using .htaccess.

The challenge is I need to pass all parameters received in the first URL to the second URL (which will also contain parameters).

So... example is:

url to forward is: https://mydomain.com/response.php?msg=Approved&id=123
I need to forward that url to:  https://mydomain.com/index.php?component=xyz&item=123&msg=Approved&id=123

I've tried several of the posts here, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QSA` flag to append query string.

Put this code in your htaccess (in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^response\.php$ /index.php?component=xyz&item=123 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @user1594099 You're welcome, glad it worked. Don't forget to validate my answer